# Just a quick question about inner product spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

So I read a theorem in my textbook which states:

"If $u$, $v$ and $w$ are vectors in a real inner product space $V$, and if $k$ is a scalar, then:
$$k\left< u, v \right> = \left< u, kv \right>.$$

There's no proof in the textbook, but using the inner product space axioms... I'm just wondering if this is correct.

Well I would start with the LHS
$$\begin{align}
k\left< u, v \right>
&= k\left< v, u \right>\textit{ by symmetry} \\
&= \left< kv, u \right>\textit{ by homogeneity} \\ 
&= \left< u, kv \right>\textit{ by symmetry.}
\end{align}$$
Is this good enough?

Comment: It really depends if your vector space is over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

Comment: You are doing fine since $<u,v>=<v,u>$ in real inner product spaces.

Answer (score 2):

What you did is correct. In general you would do it like this:

From linearity in the first argument it follows that

$$k\langle u,v\rangle=\langle ku,v\rangle\tag{1}$$

For the second argument we get from (1) and from $\langle u,v\rangle = \overline{\langle v,u\rangle}$

$$\langle u,kv\rangle=\overline{\langle kv,u\rangle}=
\bar{k}\overline{\langle v,u\rangle}=\bar{k}\langle u,v\rangle$$

Of course you don't need to worry about complex conjugation if everything is real-valued.